# Redireccionar de una URL específica a otra URL específica

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Estoy redireccionado unas URLs enviadas a un concurso, el problema que se presenta es por el cambio de registro referente y el cambio a URLs amigables

Redirecciono desde:

```
http://www.cinescuela.org/acompanamientos-pedagogicos/index.php?a=1518
```

a:

```
http://cinescuela.org/acompanamientos-pedagogicos/es/presentacion/releve-210006
```

Tengo una larga lista, y no entiendo como se referencia desde dónde, a dónde:

```
RewriteRule ^/acompanamientos-pedagogicos/index.php?a=1518$ /acompanamientos-pedagogicos/es/presentacion/releve-210006 [R=301,L]
```

**esta sentencía no me funcionó**

Tengo en mi inicio estas condiciones, porque también hubo un re direccionamiento desde el www

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa una larga lista? Si la idea es mantener cada artículo de tu web asociado a una URL amigable, y mantener eso constantemente actualizado, sería un error hacerlo 1 a 1 en el .htaccess... Para empezar, ¿cómo se relacionan `210006` con `1518`? ... Probablemente te convenga redireccionar desde PHP.

Comment: Es que hubo cambio de CMS, hubo implementación de urls amigables y hubo el cambio de www a sin www. Debo hacer una a una, porque cambian mucho en referencía

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para responder a tu pregunta directamente:

```python
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase /        #RewriteBase no es necesario en este caso, pero no influye

#Estas 3 líneas para cada redirección
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.cinescuela\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)a=158(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^acompanamientos-pedagogicos/index\.php$ http://cinescuela.org/acompanamientos-pedagogicos/es/presentacion/releve-210006 [R=301,L,NC]
```

> Nota: nunca utilices una redirección 301 hasta estar completamente seguro, porque pueden quedar en caché. Para probar, hay que usar un 302, y cambiar a 301 cuando se sabe que funciona y se tiene certeza de que nunca se volverá a modificar.

Sin embargo, esto es una solución errónea si lo que se quiere es arreglar las URLs amigables de muchos artículos, ya que no sólo conformarían una lista larga, cargando a Apache en una tarea que no corresponde, sino que te lo convierten en una solución muy difícil de mantener.

---

#### Solución recomendada

Lo que haría en este caso es:

1. Reescribir todo lo que entre a `www.cinescuela.org` (con `www`) a un PHP que se encargue de redireccionar.
2. Leer, dentro de ese PHP, en tu base de datos de qué artículo se debe redireccionar a qué id (de `158` a `210006` en el ejemplo).
3. Redireccionar desde ese php al host sin `www` correcto.

**.htaccess**

```python
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /        #RewriteBase no es necesario en este caso, pero no influye

#Reescribir a un PHP de redirección
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.cinescuela\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^acompanamientos-pedagogicos/index\.php$ redireccionar.php [L,NC]
```

**redireccionar.php**

```php
//obtenemos el parámetro
$articulo = $_GET['a'];

function obtenerId($a) {
    //Acá deberías obtener de tu base de datos a qué id corresponde
    // Lo ejemplifico con un if
    if ($a == '158')
        return 210006;
}

$id = obtenerId($articulo);


//Ahora sí, la redirección
$url = 'http://cinescuela.org/acompanamientos-pedagogicos/es/presentacion/releve-' . $id;

header('Location: ' . $url, true, 301);
die();
```

Comment: agradezco mucho el tiempo y siento que voy en buen camino con esta respuesta, encontre un htacces en el subfolder de acompanamientos-pedagogicos, por lo que se ha extendido el trabajo. De modo que el erro con el que me encuentro es diferente, como fuerzo el redirecciona solo con urls que contienen .php?, porque de aplicarlo de esta forma, modifica las condiciones seteadas anteriormente

Comment: @FelipeCanasto no termino de entender el caso, necesitaría algunos ejemplos desde qué a qué se redirecciona y cuándo no. Te recomendaría editarlo en tu pregunta, o si es un tema diferente, realizar una nueva pregunta (probablemente con un link a esta para aclarar)

Comment: Se estaban concatenando condiciones por lo que las que estaban estables se rompían y tuve que agregar el flag de END, ya con eso solucione todo. muchas Gracias

Comment: @FelipeCanasto me alegro que te haya funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Es porque lo tienes justo al revés, la redirección se hace desde la URL friendly, que es el enlace que se va a cargar, al archivo dónde están los datos

```
RewriteRule ^/acompanamientos-pedagogicos/es/presentacion/releve-210006 /acompanamientos-pedagogicos/index.php?a=1518$ [R=301,L]
```

**Edición**

Asegúrate de que permites reescribir

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: Estoy usando un RewriteBase / , no se si este influyendo porque he borrado cache y aun así parece seguir apuntando al mismo lugar del sitio.

Comment: En principio sólo necesita estar por debajo del encendido de reescribir, lo he editado. Una vez que te funcione, usa expresiones genéricas en lugar e variables numéricas, de modo que minimices el htaccess

Comment: Si yo tengo encendido el RewriteEngine On, tuve que de hecho también someter el sitio a convertirse de www. a sin www. Pero al ir al link, este conserva www, de hecho de escribirlo sin www, se autoescribe.

Comment: No debería dar problema por si lo pones por debajo de la condición que quita las www para todo el dominio